# Nested elements height doesn't correctly calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a navigation structure using `ul` container which has some `li` items and that `li` element has a `<a>` element with the `toggle` class. Underneath `<a>` element also there is `ul` container with the class name `inner`. What I'm doing is when i click on any `<a>` element a click event is call. In that event i calculate height of all children that `inner` class has but when i want to set that calculated height as a css property to that inner class it doesn't expand fully.

See Code:

```js
    function CallBackFunction() {

        var elm = $(this);

        var height = 0;

        elm.next().children().each(function () {

            height = height + $(this).outerHeight(true);
        });

        elm.next().css('max-height', height);


    }


    $('.toggle').click(CallBackFunction);
```

```css
        .parent {
            border: 1px solid black;

        }

        .inner {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
        }

        a:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="parent">

    <li>
        <a class="toggle">Link 1</a>
        <ul class="inner">

            <li>
                <p>Dummy Text</p>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="toggle">Nested Link</a>
                <div class="inner">
                    <p>Again Dummy Text</p>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in css

```
ul.inner>li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here `li` is not getting height of `p`,so need to float `li`

```js
function CallBackFunction() {

        var elm = $(this);

        var height = 0;

        elm.next().children().each(function () {

            height = height + $(this).outerHeight(true);

        });
        elm.next().css('max-height', height);


    }


    $('.toggle').click(CallBackFunction);
```

```css
 .parent {
            border: 1px solid black;

        }

        .inner {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
        }
ul.inner>li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

        a:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">

    <li>
        <a class="toggle">Link 1</a>
        <ul class="inner">

            <li>
                <p>Dummy Text</p>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="toggle">Nested Link</a>
                <div class="inner">
                    <p>Again Dummy Text</p>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but after setting to float;left `Nested Link` doesn't expand after clicking.

Comment: Its because,previous click has set `max-height: 68px;` for `ul.inner`

Comment: but height is reset when click on any `toggle` class element

Comment: yes height get reset but not to the one that is initially set.At first click `ul.inner` height is `68px;`,on second click it doesn't change,only set height `50px` for `div.inner`.If you want to see `Nested Link` you must alter `ul.inner` height.see this https://jsfiddle.net/fa58vuhv/1/